# API to get user's download folder on Mac in a sandbox app

Tags: objective-c, macos

How to get the user's downloads folder, i.e., (~/Downloads) in a sandboxed mac app?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

There is an entitlement you can add for the Downloads folder.

[According to this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html), you can add "`com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write`" to your app's entitlements file.

Comment: I have access to the folder. I mean, how to get the actual path to this folder?

Comment: You can use NSFileManager's [`URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:) method to come up with the folder that answers to the constant ["`NSDownloadsDirectory`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDownloadsDirectory). Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

```
// App Sandbox:
// Project / Target / Signing & Capabilities / App Sandbox / File Access / Downloads Folder:
// "com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write" OR "*.read-only"
- (NSURL*)downloadsURL:(NSError**)error{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *sandboxDownloadsURL = [fm URLForDirectory:NSDownloadsDirectory
                                            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                   appropriateForURL:nil
                                              create:YES
                                               error:error];
    NSURL *resolvedURL = sandboxDownloadsURL.URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath;
    return resolvedURL;
}
```