# Writing to the downloads folder in a sandboxed app

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, file-access, appstore-sandbox

[A related question asks how to write to the Downloads folder in a sandboxed app.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189531/api-to-get-users-download-folder-on-mac-in-a-sandbox-app)

I have code that does that and works at my end. However, upon submitting my app to the App Store, Apple told me I'm only allowed to write to `/Downloads/[App-Identifier]`, not to `/Downloads`.

What's the app identifier? Is it the bundle identifier? And where's the documentation pertaining to this? I've looked in the App Store Review Guidelines (Apple referred to 2.4.5(i)), in the Sandbox guide, used Google, ... no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App-Identifier` will be the Bundle ID. As to where this restriction to write to a subfolder of `~/Downloads` comes from I've no idea (it does not appear to be in the Review Guidelines, the App Sandbox Guide, etc. as you found out). You could query the review, but going another way might be easier...

You will probably be better off using a bookmark, see [Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16), and an entitlement as your linked question suggests. This will also allow you to directly store into `~/Downloads` without question - if the user selects it (put up a standard file dialog styled as a permission request, only allow folders, and preset to show the home directory; you can if you wish restrict selection to only Downloads).

HTH

Comment: I asked Apple the question directly, they will probably respond soon. I use bookmarks, but my app has a preference pane that asks users if they want to download to self-selected locations or default to the Downloads folder. Thanks btw. Looks a bit weird though, the bundle ID as a directory name. Especially because my app creates (and downloads to) directories that are named after urls ...

Comment: Well I was refered to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html).

Comment: Useful link they gave you, though it doesn't mention Downloads anywhere in it... ;-(

Comment: No :P, but it [does give an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH2-SW9) of how to do what they asked for. Their message was *"Here you can obtain some information for the file system with bundle ID and App ID etc. Basically, when the app stores files to Music, Movies, Pictures, and Downloads, folders, it should be for example, `~/Downloads/[app-identifier]/[user file]` structure."*